# Did Plant Cells Evolve from Animal, Protist, or Fungal Cells?

Tags: evolution, taxonomy, eukaryotic-cells, classification

I know protists and animals preceded plants but I am unaware of when fungi arose in relation to plants. At the moment, I cannot find a resource stating how plants evolved from existing kingdoms, or whether they evolved independently from prokaryotes. Thanks for the help, sorry if this is common knowledge.

Comment: cladistically speaking plants, fungi, and animals are all protists.

Comment: @John protist is not even a clade, actually. It was a group of all unclassified unicellular eukaryotes.

Answer (score 1):

Plants were almost always considered a separate group from fungi and animals.

As per the latest classification both animals and plants are included in the clade [Opisthokonta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opisthokont): animals and related unicellular organisms ([holozoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holozoa)) form a sister clade with [holomycota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomycota) (contains fungi and Cristidiscoidea).

Plants (archaeplastida), aveolates and rhizaria are now grouped under *Diaphoretickes* (previously they were grouped under Bikonta).

To cut short the plant and animal lineages merge only at the level of the last eukaryotic common ancestor. **This means that plants are as unrelated to fungi as they are to animals.**

Protista is no longer considered a proper clade. It used to be a group where all unclassified unicellular eukaryotes were dumped. Now these organisms have been reclassified; some are closer to animals (for e.g. Amoeba), some are closer to plants (e.g. Plasmodium) whereas some are part of a group that is distantly related to both plants and animals (for e.g. Euglena).

Have a look at this [WikiSpecies site](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Eukaryota) for a detailed classification (latest and historical). It also cites proper references.